# Android TextView show text as a link

Tags: android, hyperlink, textview

I have TextView in my app that I want to show text as a link.

I have "See Map" string, and I want to show it as a hyperlink (blue and underlined).

I'm trying this:

```
tvSeeMap.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.see_map));
    Linkify.addLinks(tvSeeMap, Linkify.ALL);
```

but it won't work.

Comment: http://blog.iangclifton.com/2010/12/30/android-textview-and-html-links/. Have a look at this link. This should help you.

Comment: you want it just to be shown as hyperlink or shown and behave as hyperlink (clickable)?

Comment: just to be shown as a hyper link, i will open google map app on click.

Comment: show example text you want Linkify to process

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've found workaround

```
 String tempString = new String(getResources().getString(R.string.see_map));
 SpannableString content = new SpannableString(tempString);
 content.setSpan(new UnderlineSpan(), 0, tempString.length(), 0);
 tvSeeMap.setText(content);
 tvSeeMap.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
```

Simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

use

```
Linkify.addLinks(tvSeeMap,Linkify.WEB_URLS);
```

instead of

```
Linkify.addLinks(tvSeeMap, Linkify.ALL);
```

to show an hyperlink or web url as link in textView

Comment: `Linkify.ALL` is 0x0F while `Linkify.WEB_URLS` is 0x01 - is this a bug you are addressing with this change?

Answer (score 0):

Does the link have the "http://" prefix? If not, try adding it. Or it might be that the link does not have spaces before and after it